# Installing Laravel On Subdirectory, Some Routes Won't Work

Tags: php, laravel-5, deployment, hosting

I'm installing my project on my friend's server, so I have to install it to a sub directory inside **public_html**. So, I created a subfolder named **lv** `(public_html/lv)`.

you can check on picture below

[list directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ZSx.png)

here is my route

```
Route::get('spot/{slug}', 'userController@detail_spot');
```

and here is my method userController

```
public function detail_spot($slug, Request $request){ ... }
```

this is my page that doesn't work

[notfound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deFNd.png)

another web page that working fine

[working page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAUib.png)

thanks, i hope you guys can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Laravel serves from public folder and the folder above it. *index.php present inside public folder

Comment: @danishhashmi i'm not really understand about what your said, but, yeah i can say my index.php inside the public folder. I was follow tutorial installing laravel on many site, i'm just wonder about my case that need to install laravel inside subdirectory

Comment: please.. help me

Answer (score 0):

you cant sub folder project in project, indonesian kan?
kalo pengen 1 server dengan 2 project, harus pakai sub domain, bukan sub folder project.
example :

1. wisataku.com
2. pantai.wisataku.com

mungkin maksutnya seperti ini ya

Comment: oh, lebih mudah pake sub domain kah mas? di sub domain itu kita taroh semua project laravel kita atau cuma public folder aja?

Comment: okeh, jadi gimana ini mas? saya sudah bikin sub domain dan semua yang ada di project saya saya lgs masukin ke sub domain itu ya?

Comment: pakai sub doimain server aja, jangan sub domain routes, nah nanti tinggal arahin aja ke folder project masing"

Comment: atau kalau bingung, pake routes sub domain, jadi mulai dari controller dimasukkan ke http dia, trus tinggal diarahin aja, bukan bikin project baru, dan viewnya juga dimasukkan ke resources project temen, tapi harus edit juga views template masing"

Comment: project temen pake CI mas, jadi saya remake pake laravel. dan make subdoimainpun gak solve, tetep aja not found waktu buka spot/slug